# How to increase speed of Browsermob Proxy?

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I'm playing with Browsermob Proxy and a simple script with it (below) works extremely slow. I guess, it is the time it takes to start a new server.

If this is the case, is there a way to start a server to use it between different script executions?

Or if this is not the case, what can be slowing down my script?

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import json


server = Server("/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

print(1)
profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=r'./')
print(2)
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
print(4)

opts = Options()
opts.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'./geckodriver', options=opts)
print(5)


proxy.new_har()
driver.get("http://value.to")
proxy.har # returns a HAR JSON blob
#print(proxy.har)
print("analytics in value.to:")
for entry in proxy.har["log"]["entries"]:
    if "google-analytics" in entry["request"]["url"]:
        print(entry["request"]["url"])

print("\n\n\n")

proxy.new_har()
driver.get("http://insightwhale.com")
proxy.har # returns a HAR JSON blob
#print(proxy.har)

print("analytics in insightwhale:")
for entry in proxy.har["log"]["entries"]:
    if "google-analytics" in entry["request"]["url"]:
        print(entry["request"]["url"])

print(json.dumps(proxy.har, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
file = open("____tmp.txt", "w")
file.write(json.dumps(proxy.har, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
file.close()


server.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, god knows why this: "profile_directory=r'./'" was slowing down the script. Without this parameter of FirefoxProfile everything works fast.